# Call a method of a web component and respond to events

Tags: events, methods, dart, dart-webui

I'm working on a Dart project where I have created a custom element with the Web_ui package that has some animation.  What I was hoping to do is to have within the dart code for the element something like this....

```dart
class MyElement extends WebComponent {
   ...

   void StartAnimation() { ... }

   ...
}
```

and then in the main() function of the dart app itself I have something like this...

```dart
void main() {
    MyElement elm = new MyElement();
    elm.StartAnimation();  // Kicks off the animation
}
```

The Dart editor tells me that Directly constructing a web component is not currently supported.  It then says to use WebComponent.forElement -- but I'm not clear on how to use that to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 3):

While you can't yet import web components into a Dart file, you can access them via `query()` and `.xtag`. `xtag` gives you a reference the web component instance that the element is associated with. You do have to be careful that you allow the Web UI setup to complete so that  `xtag` is given a value.

Here's an example:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

main() {
  Timer.run(() {
    var myElement = query('#my-element').xtag;
    myElement.startAnimation();
  });
}
```

This will get better with the ability to import components, directly subclass Element and maybe some lifecycle events that guarantee that you get the correct class back from a `query()`. This is what the exemple should look like in the future:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';
import 'package:my_app/my_element.dart';

main() {
  MyElement myElement = query('#my-element');
  myElement.startAnimation();
}
```

Comment: I've been trying that, but myElement is always null.  Even the editor colors the variable purple to indicate that it will be null.  And of-course when I try to run the code, I get an error "The null object does not have a method 'StartAnimation'."

Comment: OK, just got it.  I see what you mean about needing to make sure enough time has passed so that xtag has a value.  Is there any better way that you might know of rather than a timer to know when xtag is ready?

Comment: Not that I know of, and I believe it's less of an issue of an amount of time passing that letting the event stack unwind, so `Timer.run()` should be sufficient.